# Activity is getting killed by android when home button is pressed

Tags: android

I am working on Location based application ,which get the latitude and longitude by using  android location services and sending  it to the server by an asyncTask .The problem is when I start the application and press the home button the application is getting stopped .why ?? Please help me .

Comment: can you post yours code..please check carefully with all lifecycle methods

Comment: Can you please check your onPause() method? When user press home button onPause of the activity will get called

Comment: I have stated my asyncTask in onStart () method .what can I do in onPause () ,and onStop() and onResume() .please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the activity declaration in the manifest and add the following attribute:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

It will prevent the activity from restarting.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for more information.

Comment: Google's recommendation for tasks like sending the current location to a server is to place it in a background service and not using an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Developer Options and Uncheck "**Do not keep activities**"

Comment: This is least possible case. I guess. Most possibly he is messing up something in lifecycle methods.

Comment: @bipin  I have already unchecked ,could you please tell me what should I put in onPause and onResume()

Comment: @user3185584 it is almost impossible to say where you messed. So please provide your code so that we could help you

Answer (score 0):

This is old question and probably won't help OP, but maybe others might benefit from this answer. I noticed very similar behaviour when I had set android:noHistory on the activity that was behaving this way in Android Manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name="SomeActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">
    </activity>
```

Of course you may need this flag, in which case you need to find workaround if the behaviour (such as `onSaveInstanceState()` being not called) causes you problems